# ERROR: failed to connect to camera service @ Android marshmallow

Tags: android, camera

Im trying to build a camera app (Im pretty new at this)
When I run the application on real device its gives me this Error:

```
    05-26 13:16:37.504 14076-14076/involved.pose9 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: involved.pose9, PID: 14076
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
                                                                at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:511)
                                                                at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:368)
                                                                at involved.pose9.CameraActivity.surfaceCreated(CameraActivity.java:63)
                                                                at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:582)
                                                                at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:177)
                                                                at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6060)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

This is my Class

```
    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    import java.io.IOException;

    public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
public Camera mCamera;
boolean mPreviewRunning;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if (mPreviewRunning) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }
    Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
    //p.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    mCamera.setParameters(p);
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(arg0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mCamera.startPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera = Camera.open();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mPreviewRunning = false;
    mCamera.release();
}

Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {
    }
};
}
```

What is wrong here? Thanks in advance..

I also declare permissions in manifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware." />
```

Comment: For marshamllow you need RunTimePermission please refer this https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @AbhishekPatel wouldn't the exception be different if that was the case? Though you're right, in M you need to check for permissions. Given the log I'm not sure this is the case though.

Comment: @Allie if its permission problem you are going to get this error. You will not be able to access camera and asking permission in manifest will not work :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Marshmallow : java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172397/android-marshmallow-java-lang-runtimeexception-fail-to-connect-to-camera-serv)

Comment: So what should I do? I have read the Link mr Patel send me but I dont understand what to do.. Thanks for quick response and sorry for beeing noob...

Comment: see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/37269354/6127411

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to give `android.hardware.Camera` permission programmatically.

> MANIFEST PERMISSIONS WON'T WORK on Android 6
>
> With marshmallow(newest version of Android). We have got some
>   restrictions in Using **Sensitive** permissions like :
>   Storage,Contacts access, etc..In edition to give these permissions in
>   manifest, We need to request them from users at **Runtime**.

For more details refer this : [Android M permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-permissions.html#version_specific_details_permissions_in_m)

Add this code in your activity :

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        int hasCameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

        } 
        if (!permissions.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), 111);
        }
    }


}
```

Add this after `onActivityResult` :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 111: {
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    System.out.println("Permissions --> " + "Permission Granted: " + permissions[i]);


                } else if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    System.out.println("Permissions --> " + "Permission Denied: " + permissions[i]);

                }
            }
        }
        break;
        default: {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In marshmellow onwards the OS permisson are supposed to be taken at runtime. The camera permission also has to be take at run time Please check the below link to see how to ask permission at runtime. 
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

**Quick Solution** :
This is a fix but you can use for current marshmellow version
Try adding this in your build.gradle file

```
targetSdkVersion 22
```

Comment: This worked but it wont run at Marshmallow devices.. Thanks though.. :)

Comment: Wont run in the sense app doesnt launch in marshmellow ?

Comment: @AllieFly it will run in marshmallow. But by default all the permissions will be granted. better to handle the permissions at runtime rather than making the targetSdk version lower to 23

Answer (score 1):

on Marshmallow you have to ask user for grant permission at run time something like this

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);

if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
//user granted you
}else{
//the user denied your permission
}
```

Comment: But this is for calendar. What permission is for camera and where should I write this?

Also should I delete manifest permissions?

Comment: no you have to keep the manifest permission , yes just edit the code and replace CALENDAR with CAMERA permisison