# Paypal payment : How to get success request when loading the paypal in webview

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

**Edit:**

After paypal login, I could successfully complete transaction.But I need to match the *successUrl* in paypal to verify both url is same and then display successful toast message.

But I am not getting success url from payment.So I can't match it.Below I have posted the relevant code:

**WebActivity.java:**

```
public class PaypalWebActivity extends Activity {
    
    private WebView webView;
    
    String payUrlStr;
    
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    String successUrl;
    
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.paypal_web_layout);

        successUrl = LOAD_WEBVIEW_PAYMENT_PAYPAL_SUCCESS;

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PaypalWebActivity.this, "", "Please wait..", false);

        loadWebViewPaypal();
        
    }

    private void loadWebViewPaypal() {
        
        payUrlStr = LOAD_WEBVIEW_PAYMENT_PAYPAL(PAGE_ID);       
        
        Log.e("payUrlStr", ""+payUrlStr);
        
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl(payUrlStr);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        WebSettings settings= webView.getSettings();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
           }
        
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.e("Loading url...", url);
                view.loadUrl(url);
                
               String loadWebUrl = view.getUrl();
                
                Log.e("loadWebUrl", ""+loadWebUrl);
                
                return true;
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.e("Finished url...", url);
                
                String webUrl = view.getUrl();
                
                Log.e("webUrl", ""+webUrl);
                
                
                if(webUrl.substring(0,95).equals(successUrl)){
                    
                    Log.e("Getting Success Request", "Test");
                    
                }else{
                    
                    Log.e("Failed to get Request", "Test");
                    
                }
                
                if(dialog.isShowing()){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {
                
                Log.e("Error in url...", description);
                Log.e("Error in failingUrl...", failingUrl);
                
            }
            
        });        
        
    }
    

    
}
```

**Manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

check this [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114725/discussion-between-pp-pduan-and-naruto).step by step I put screenshots and added content for clear understanding.

I am getting this **error** message.So cant able to match success request:

> 06-15 18:12:59.894: I/chromium(3273): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Mixed
> Content: The page at
> 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?SESSION=LTy9Q59%5fia3wiAdHTQjgQxvUF1BTzLjgXgelCew4AS%2dGAutAfB5WjZXVuX8&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8dcce3e160f5b9538489e17951d2c62172'
> was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets
> an insecure endpoint
> 'http://www.myapi-entertainment.com/page_managements/page_featured_subscription_payment_success/4. this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.
> https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?SESSION=LTy9Q59%5fia3wiAdHTQjgQxvUF1BTzLjgXgelCew4AS%2dGAutAfB5WjZXVuX8&dispatch=5885d80a13c0db1f8e263663d3faee8dcce3e160f5b9538489e17951d2c62172
> (0)

This is my success response "http://www.myapi-entertainment.com/page_managements/page_featured_subscription_payment_success/4" -> Changed server name.

is it possible to match success request with paypal? If I get any suggestion, it will  be helpful to me.

Comment: I think u need to ask permission at runtime

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458157/error-failed-to-connect-to-camera-service-android-marshmallow/37458251#37458251

Comment: Put up your web page code of `payUrlStr` please, did you integrate with simple payment button or PayPal Express API in there?

Comment: @pp_pduan I need to [discuss](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114725/discussion-between-pp-pduan-and-naruto). can you please come there.

Comment: Can you enable https on your server and use an **https** _success response url_

Comment: @Nurato You can use [letsencrypt.org](https://letsencrypt.org) for enabling https if you dont have one already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I understand with your query is, you have an URL of your Website which perform payment using Paypal, and in Mobile app you are performing the same using the Webview(not Paypal SDK).

***Yes***, you can get the `callback` by doing some coding at your WEB end.

**Meaning:**

Whenever any user navigate to Payment page then your Server must know whether User visited from Website or through Mobile Webview, Server can send `additional parameter key` to any Payment gateway for their custom logic. Later once Payment transaction completed, Payment gateway will return the same `additional parameter key` alongwith the result(Success or Failure).

*Note: Every Payment gateway has a setting of `Redirection url for Success/Failure`*

Once Paypal redirect to result url(Success/Failure) after Transaction gets completed, Server then again check whether the request has been made from Website or from Mobile Webview with the help of `additional parameter key`; check case below...

**If from Mobile Webview**

- Success: Redirected to URL `www.myserver.com/success`
- Failure: Redirected to URL `www.myserver.com/failure`

**If from Webiew then `Normal flow`**

Now in your Mobile's Webview

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("www.myserver.com/success"))
                  //Success Toast
                else if(url.equalsIgnoreCase("www.myserver.com/failure"))
                   //Failure Toast
                return true;
            }

});
```

That's it.

Comment: Hi I tried your answer.But I am not getting success response url in log.So I can't handle that one.

Comment: It(success response url) wont come automatically, you need to code at Server end. Read 'Meaning'.

Comment: @Stephen This answer contains detailed explanation with the example code so this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

Paypal returns json response after successful payment like below

```
{
  "client": {
    "environment": "sandbox",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.14.1",
    "platform": "Android",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
  },
  "response": {
    "create_time": "2016-06-15T11:38:04Z",
    "id": "PAY-6CN54299U76194116K5QT4BY",
    "intent": "sale",
    "state": "approved"
  },
  "response_type": "payment"
}
```

You need to check response json object. if state is approved that means paypal payment is successful. Then you can check on Paypal website for current transactions.

Make Sure you have followed below steps:
1)  
 `private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT = 1;
 private static String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT=PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;`
//It will be PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION for live mode.
2)

```
// note that these credentials will differ between live & sandbox environments.
private static final String CONFIG_CLIENT_ID = "ATBvU5urlaPOhpCrAhFsoG4u63RvNoKUocFPs9yR5q_sbM0yecZawUjoJhIilW8DNg5RrJcRHgRuEP_1";

private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
                                    .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
                                    .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                                            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
                                    .merchantName("Example Merchant")
                                    .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
                                    .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PayPalService.class);
                            intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
                            getActivity().startService(intent);
```

Comment: @Naruto I have integrated Paypal by following this and my payment process is working fine. Let me know if you get any issue in this.

Comment: I need to use webview to load paypal.Moreover I am not having any paypal key.They created the account and gave login access.thats it

Comment: @Naruto You have paypal login credentials. Did you created app on PayPal??

Comment: Please check this [discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114725/discussion-between-pp-pduan-and-naruto). I have added step by step procedure.I am not famliar with paypal

Comment: OP not using Paypal MOBILE SDK instead its a Web redirect.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

It seems from the screen shots you're embedding a subscription page into your webview, and trying to match `successUrl` with the return URL.

1. Check the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642895/setting-paypal-return-url-and-making-it-auto-return) to set up the retrun URL first in your profile
2. Obtain the URL `String webUrl = webView.getUrl();` if you want to make match/ verification with the defined `successUrl`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above,

u need to check response json object. if state is approved that means paypal payment is successful.then you can check on Paypal website for current transactions

Answer (score 1):

I am getting a Payment success or failure request using this below Codes:

```
private void loadWebViewPaypal() {

        payUrlStr = LOAD_WEBVIEW_PAYMENT_PAYPAL(PAGE_ID);       

        Log.e("payUrlStr", "" + payUrlStr);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(payUrlStr);


        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        WebSettings settings= webView.getSettings();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode( WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW );
           }


    }

    public class WebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

            Log.e("Page Started", ""+url);

            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);



            if(url.contains(successUrl)) {

                Log.e("Getting Success Request", "Test");

                Intent i = new Intent(PaypalWebActivity.this, TabhostActivity.class);

                PAYPAL_WEB_BACK = "fulfilled";
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            } else if(url.equalsIgnoreCase(failureUrl)) {

                Intent i = new Intent(PaypalWebActivity.this, TabhostActivity.class);

                PAYPAL_WEB_BACK = "fulfilled";
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            Log.e("Override Url", ""+url);

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            Log.e("Finished Url :", "" + url);

            if(dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```